# Cannot access 'number': it is internal in 'CardParams'

Tags: kotlin

I have been trying to compile my app in android studio  but I am getting this error "Cannot access 'number': it is internal in 'CardParams'"

```js
    val cardNumber = binding.cardInput.cardParams!!.number
                val expiryYear = binding.cardInput.cardParams!!.expYear
                val expiryMonth = binding.cardInput.cardParams!!.expMonth
                val cvc = binding.cardInput.cardParams!!.cvc
                val token = "{\"cardNumber\":${cardNumber},\"cvv\":${cvc},\"expiryMonth\":${expiryMonth},\"expiryYear\":${expiryYear}}"
                chargeAccount(amountDouble, token)
            }

            else -> {
                binding.waitingForPayment = true
                GetPaymentLink(selectedPayment!!.id, amount = amountDouble, currency = currency!!, serverUrl = Config.Backend).execute<GetPaymentLinkResult> {
                    binding.waitingForPayment = false
                    when (it) {
                        is RemoteResponse.Success -> {
                            val intent = Intent(this@ChargeAccountActivity, PaymentActivity::class.java)
                            intent.putExtra("redirectionUrl", it.body.url)
                            startActivityForResult(intent, WEB_PAYMENT_CALLBACK)
                        }

                        is RemoteResponse.Error -> {
                            it.error.showAlert(this)
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`internal` means [it can only be accessed from within the same module](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#classes-and-interfaces). Is `cardInput` in another module, or some library you're using?

You're not meant to be touching `cardParams` directly, basically. If it's under your control you could make it public, or add a public getter function

Comment: can you modifiy the above and send code please it will be greatful

Comment: If you can't then I definitely can't!

Comment: @ShaheenBlaze The problem isn't with the code above; it's with the `CardParams` class.  You either need to update that to increase the scope of `number`, or find some other way to do what you need to do.